# node js simple chat app delay on event trigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i prepared a simple chat system while practicing node.js. but theres a problem while sending messages. quite a good amount of delay taking place while sending messages and i couldnt figure out why. can anyone help me how to improve attached code ?

server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.on('messageSend', function(data) {
        client.broadcast.emit('messageRecieve', data);
    });
});

http.listen(9090, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port 9090');
    io.on('connect', function(socket) {
        console.log("Connection established : " + socket.client.conn.remoteAddress);
    })
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Socket Test</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
        function messageSend() {
            var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
            console.log(message);
            var ul = document.getElementById("messageNode");
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
            li.setAttribute("style", "font-style : italic; color : red;");
            ul.appendChild(li);
            socket.emit('messageSend', message);
        }

        socket.on('messageRecieve', function(data) {
            var message = data;
            var ul = document.getElementById("messageNode");
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
            ul.appendChild(li);
            console.log(message);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="messageInput" type="text"> <button onclick="messageSend()">Send</button><br>
<ul id="messageNode">

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He does not recieve his own messages from the server. "Broadcasting means sending a message to everyone else except for the socket that starts it." Also. I do not see anything weird here that should slow down the code. Your computer must be the culprit somehow

Comment: creating elements is not a performance issue, but i tried to code a simple log for sent & recieve message (sent are italic red, recieved standart style). problem is when send event is triggered theres a delay like 4 or 5 seconds, sometimes more sometimes less. i tried to connect from a different host and its still same.

Comment: Your code looks very similar. But following the official socket.io guide might be worth a try https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: socket.io code works like a charm but mine still have some delay that i couldnt figure out. theres something i m missing :S

Comment: As you are using `<button onclick="messageSend()">` for sending message. You can try with `<form></form>` because maybe the javascript is the reason for that delay.

Answer (score 0):

the official socket.io example sends the message to everyone, including yourself

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

You sent to everyone except yourself (which is the most accurate method)

```
io.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.on('messageSend', function(data) {
        client.broadcast.emit('messageRecieve', data);
    });
});
```

The reason for your slowdown is probably becouse your browser puts your out-of-focus tabs in a sort of sleep mode, which makes it update much less frequently... If you compare your code vs socket.io's code between computer and phone via lan. I would guess the speed for your server-sent message would be the same

Right now you are basically competing versus socket.io's "optimistic updates". It pushes the message to your client directly without waiting for the server, which your own code does. As well as browser out-of-focus low priority mode

Comment: after trying some other versions, i discovered that Glutch and Rupesh have some points they are right. Forexample if i put my inputbox and button in <form></form> element messages are sent immediately but in that case theres another problem occurs.. page reloads and fires a disconnect connect event and also my chat log is destroyed because page reloads. so i tried not to reload when button is clicked with `onclick="sendMessage();return false;"`. but with this version delay is back. so for some reason as Glutch mentioned my browser enters a sleep mode, that i can not understand why..

Comment: at last ! `var io = require('socket.io')(server, { wsEngine: 'ws' });` fixed the problem and it works perfect !